# How to make text appear and dissappear with carousel

Tags: html, css, carousel, caroufredsel

I would like to make text appear and dissappears when the image slides.I want the same effect on
the  other images with different text.
 I Want to create a Similar effect like in the sliding banner shown here: 
    http://www.creativelive.com/ 
    this is my code so far 
**My HTML**:

```
<div id="carousel" class="container_24">
  <div class="grid_24">
    <div class="spotlight">
      <span class="text">This text should appear and dissappear</span>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/abstract-q-c-960-390-10.jpg" width="960" height="390"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_24">
    <div class="spotlight">
      <span class="text">This text should appear and dissappear</span>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/abstract-q-c-960-390-9.jpg" width="960" height="390"></a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="grid_24">
    <div class="spotlight">
      <span class="text">This text should appear and dissappear</span> 
      <a href="#"> <img src="images/abstract-q-c-960-390-8.jpg" width="960" height="390"></a>
    </div>
  </div>        
  <div class="grid_24">
    <div class="spotlight">
      <span class="text">This text should appear and dissappear</span>
      <a href="#"> <img src="images/abstract-q-c-960-390-3.jpg" width="960" height="390"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Css**

```
.spotlight a {
  display:block;
  width:950px;
  height:390px;
  float:left;

}
.text {
  color:red;
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
  margin:100px 10px 0 800px;
  z-index:50;
}
```

Also I am using the `caroufredsel plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

did you give the container of the slider `position: relative;`and the captions something like `position absolute; bottom: 10px; right; 0px`

position absolute inside an position relative element will place someting that is right: 0 and top :0 at the right top of the container. And what part are you animating?

What are you exactly seeing? could you post a image or url? or jsFiddle?

this is what i have made a while ago:

```
<figure id="slider">
                <ul>
                    <!-- slide 1 -->
                    <li>                        
                        <div class="inside">caption 1a</div>                        
                        <div class="outside">caption 1b.</div>                      
                        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="slide">
                    </li>
                    <!-- slide 2-->
                    <li>                    
                        <div class="inside">caption 1b </div>                       
                        <div class="outside">caption 2b</div>   
                        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="slide">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </figure>
```

and the js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
if($("#slider ul").length != 0) {
    $("#slider ul").carouFredSel({
        auto : {
            duration: 950
        },
        swipe : { onTouch : true, onMouse : false },
        scroll      : {
            fx          : "crossfade"
        },
        items       : {
            visible     : 1,
            width       : 950,
            height      : 503,
        },
    });
}
```

});

and the css:

```
#slider{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 503px;
    max-width: 1250px;
    position: relative;
}
#slider img{
    z-index: 90;
}
#header #slider .inside{
    overflow: hidden;
    font: 18px/28px 'Michroma', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 152px;
    right: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    z-index: 99;
    background: #55432e;
}
#slider .outside{
    overflow: hidden;
    font: 13px/18px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    bottom: 0px;
    color: #2f2518;
    width: 95%;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    z-index: 99;
    background: url(../images/transparant-bg.png);
}
#slider ul li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: i am animating the plugin on the #carousel and it works fine ,also position relative to slider and absolute to text and works fine too.my prob is to achieve the appear and dissappear of the text and green box like the one on the right side of the banner here http://www.creativelive.com/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ak9GG/1/  you will see the images on top of each other because could not run the jquery plugin

Comment: I am also trying the @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn in css,but not working properly.Any suggestions please?